# Gets the mutual boolean state of different boolean values compared

Tags: c#

**scenario1**:
hasError1 is false
hasError2 is true

**scenario2**:
hasError1 is true
hasError2 is true

true must win in both scenarios. how would you assign both hasError1 and hasErro2 to a third variable to get the correct error state?

Comment: Are those the only cases that should result in true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read up on your [Boolean Algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra) you will see you need to "OR" (`|`) the values together.

```
bool b1 = false;
bool b2 = true;
bool b3 = b1 | b2; // b3 is assigned the value of b1 ORed with b2
// b3 has the value "true" now
```

Note you will often see `b1 || b2` used instead of `b1 | b2`. This works the same way, and the [details of the difference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) are unlikely to be important to you

Finally, I would suggest reading up on the use of "Truth tables". These are a really good way to understand boolean algebra (AND, OR, XOR, NOT).

Answer (score 3):

The operator `||` :

```
var hasError3 = hasError1 || hasError2;
```